# Smartmenus default style is overriding custom style

Tags: jquery, html, css, menu, smartmenus

Ok so I have a very weird issue with smartmenus. According to a client of mine the default style for smartmenus is overriding my custom style for the menu.

[Here is what it looks like according to them](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FOPin.png)

I believe they are using Windows 10 and possible an older version of Chrome but I haven't been able to find that issue anywhere I test it in Browser Stack.

https://diamondbraces.com/

This is a link to the site if you want to check it out. Im not able to reproduce the issue. I would like to just know where I can look to try and figure this problem out.

Comment: can you please ask for screen size & resolution

Comment: What is it supposed to look like? What order do you have the various CSS links positioned in?